# WSL drvfs mount issues -- "cannot mount: read-only"

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a couple of issues with mounting drives in WSL (Win10 Linux Subsystem).

I have a network share mounted on drive M: locally - and I have read/write access in Windows.

When I try and mount it using WSL:

```
$ sudo mount -t drvfs M: /mnt/m
mount: /mnt/m: cannot mount M: read-only.
$
```

I tried different mount options, still the mount always gets rejected with "read-only".   (At the same time, mounting my network home works fine)
And mounting a different network share also works;  but can I find out, what's different about this network share? ..and - any idea of how to get around it?  (Particularly given, that I *DO* have access to the drive within windows)

Comment: Did you try the [wsl.conf](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/) method?

Comment: doesn't seem to help;  I also tried adding the suggested "metadata" option separately at mount time - same problem.

Comment: Strange thing about the error message - why is the "read-only" a problem? Even if I specify mount option "ro" (read-only), it still doesn't mount the share with the same error message "read-only".  The same happens when trying to mount with option "rw"...

Comment: btw - has anyone else even seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I met "cannot mount: read-only" issue when I tried to mount other network drive in WSL.
But I solved by writting address number directly instead of Server name.

---

```
~$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.1 -U% <br/>
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated   

        Sharename       Type      Comment   
        ---------       ----      -------    
        ebook           Disk      ipTime1TB's ebook in ipTIME External   

        Server               Comment 
        ---------            -------    
        RT-AC68R-F528        RT-AC68R-F528    

        Workgroup            Master         
        ---------            -------  
        WORKGROUP            RT-AC68R-F528

~$ mkdir -p ~/my_mount/ebook

~$ sudo mount -t drvfs //RT-AC68R-F528/ebook ~/my_mount/ebook<br/>
mount: /home/catholic2020/my_mount/ebook: cannot mount //RT-AC68R-F528/ebook read-only.<br/>
<3>init: (2018) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:360: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000<br/>
No error information<br/>

~$ sudo mount -t drvfs //192.168.1.1/ebook ~/my_mount/ebook      
~$
```

---

goodluck!